# Is $\{a+b\sqrt{3}\mid a, b \in \Bbb Z\}$ Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've got an question to prove

> Let $R = \Bbb Z [\sqrt 3] = \{a+b\sqrt{3}\mid a, b \in \Bbb Z\}$. Prove that R forms a ring with the addition and multiplication considered R as a subset of the field of real numbers. Find all units in this ring.

While I am proceeding with a proof of $R$ to be ring, for its requirement to have multiplicative inverse, I've got ${a\over a^2-3b^2}-{b\over a^2-3b^2}\sqrt3$ where each coefficient not in $\Bbb Z$

IIs $\{a+b\sqrt{3}\mid a, b \in \Bbb Z\}$ really to be Ring?

> Additionally, for unit in R, one must be represented in a form of  ${a\over a^2-3b^2}-{b\over a^2-3b^2}\sqrt3$ and those coefficient must be in $\Bbb Z$.

Is it sufficient to say $\text{unit in }R = \{ {a\over a^2-3b^2}-{b\over a^2-3b^2}\sqrt3\mid {a\over a^2-3b^2}, {b\over a^2-3b^2} \in \Bbb Z\}?$

Comment: The last line is a promising start. I would formulate it to state that $a+b\sqrt3$ is a unit if and only if both $a/(a^2-3b^2)$ and $b/(a^2-3b^2)$ are integers. After all, your calculation with multiplicative inverses shows that the inverse of $a+b\sqrt3$ is $(a-b\sqrt3)/(a^2-3b^2)$. This may be sufficient. I cannot creep into your teachers mind and tell what they want at this point. To be on the safe side I would list some pairs of integers $(a,b)$ such that the condition is met. A suggestion in my answer then gives you infinitely many units.

Comment: mathematics.. is always tricky to me..

Comment: why infinitely many units or not(cardinally? or finiteness is so important? in this unit context)

Comment: Once you locate a unit $>1$ what can you say about the size of its powers? But, I'm not sure this is what your teacher is after. If I were to give this exercise to a class (I actually have essentially done just that!) then I would be happy for them to find solutions other than $(a,b)=(\pm1,0)$ and improvise it from that point on.

Answer (score 2):

A ring does not need to have multiplicative inverses. A field does.

Comment: right.. it must have multiplication identity not inverse..

Comment: @delinco Not everyone even requires a multiplicative identity.

Comment: you mean there still a ring which has no multiplicative identity $1_R$?

Comment: Opinion variés but some do not require an identity.  A simple example is the even integers.  Wolfram lists it as optional: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html

Comment: @delinco the even integers form a ring without multiplicative unit

Comment: @delinco However,you are asked to find the units so you are asked to find the elements that have an inverse.  In the regular integers, these are $1$ and $-1$.  So, you need to continue trying to find inverses.

Comment: @badjohn a bit confusing different from my textbook, Fraleigh's one.

Comment: @badjohn added some question about unit in R. Would you check it for me?

Comment: @delinco Indeed a bit confusing.  There is no international standards body for mathematics setting the rules.  In many cases, pretty much everyone agrees.  In some cases, there is some variation but all of the popular variants are equivalent.  In a few cases, significantly different definitions are in common use.  Here is an example: some require rings to have an identity and some do not.  Your book may require it but watch out when reading other books as they may not.  Also, when posting here it is worth saying which convention you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The set $R$ is a ring with respect to the usual operations. The easiest way of proving that is to show that it is a subring of a known ring. Here I recommend that you prove that $R$ is a subring of the ring of real numbers $(\Bbb{R},+,\cdot,0,1)$. This is a simple application of the so called [*subring criterion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring#Subring_test) that I invite you to verify yourself.

The question about units is more difficult. It turns out that there are infinitely many of those. Therefore a list is not expected. Judging from the rest of the question I expect that you are A) to exhibit infinitely many units with the aid of powers of a non-trivial unit you are to find, and possibly B) to show that $u=a+b\sqrt3$ is a unit of $R$ if and only if $v=a-b\sqrt3$ is its inverse. We can say a lot more about the group of units of $R$, but that question is met only (AFAICT) in the context of [algebraic-number-theory](/questions/tagged/algebraic-number-theory), and my judgement tells me that you are not expected to know that material. At least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

The axioms you have to check are (if $R$ is to be a "ring with unit"):

1) $R$ is a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) with respect to the addition

2) $R$ is a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) with respect to multiplication